# Are these two definition of maximal normal equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Definition.** Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. We call $H$ *maximal-normal* if $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

**Definition.** Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. We call $H$ *maximal_normal* if $H \trianglelefteq N \trianglelefteq G$ implies $H=N$ or $N=G$.

Obviously, every *maximal-normal* subgroup is *maximal_normal*. What I haven't been able to figure out is whether *maximal_normal* implies *maximal-normal*.

---

Here's my attempt:
Let $H$ be a *maximal_normal* subgroup of $G$. Then there is a lattice isomorphism between the subgroups of $G$ containing $H$ and the subgroups of $G/H$.(I tried to use the correspondence theorem, nothing seemed to work!)

---

Can someone provide me a hint or a counterexample? I would appreciate it.

Comment: It may help that if $N$ is any subgroup of $G$ containing $H$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N$. But maybe there are cases where $N$ is not normal in $G$. This is where you might look for a counterexample.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I already observed that and I tried to sketch the subgroup lattices of many well known finite groups but unfortunately every normal subgroup tends to sit inside some *maximal-normal* subgroups. This makes me that these definitions are equivalent in finite groups.

Comment: If $N$ is maximal according to the second definition, then $G/N$ is simple. If $N$ is maximal according to the first definition, then $G/N$ has no proper nontrivial subgroups. Are those two statements equivalent?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the help. If we take $G = A_5 \times \mathbb Z  _{2}$ and $N=\{ id \} \times \mathbb Z _2$ then $G/N$ is isomorphic to $A_5$ but if the two definitions were equivalent then $A_5$ would have no proper trivial subgroups which is not true.

Comment: Why so involved? Take $G=A_5$, $N=\{e\}$. Then $N$ satisfies the second definition, but not the first.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Would you consider making your comment into an answer?